# Simple group of order $p^2 q r$, where $p, q, r$ are distinct primes, is isomorphic to $A_5$

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

As stated, I need to prove that, up to isomorphism, the only simple group of order $p^2 q r$, where $p, q, r$ are distinct primes, is $A_5$ (the alternating group of degree 5).

Now I know the following: if $G$ is a simple group and $|G| = 60$, then $G$ is isomorphic to $A_5$. However, I don't even know how to begin the proof that $|G| = 60$, or anything similar.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sketch solution. I can give more detail, but it depends on which results you are familiar with.

Let $G$ be simple of order $p^2qr$.
By Burnside's Transfer Theorem, $p$ must be the smallest of the three primes because, if for example $q$ was smallest then $G$ would have a normal $q$-complement so would not be simple.

Let $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$. Then $P$ must be properly contained in its normalizer, since otherwise there would be a normal $p$-complement by Burnside's Transfer Theorem. So we can assume that $|N_G(P)| = p^2q$. Let $Q \in {\rm Syl}_q(N_G(P))$, so $|Q|=q$.

We cannot have $Q < C_G(P)$ or again there would be a normal $p$-complement, so $|Q|$ must divide $|{\rm Aut}(P)|$, which is equal to $p(p-1)$ if $P$ is cyclic and $p(p^2-1)$ if it is $C_p \times C_p$.

But since $q$ is prime and $p<q$, the only possibility is $p=2$, $q=3$, and $PQ \cong A_4$.

But now $|{\rm Syl}_r(G)|$ must divide $|G:R|=12$ and also be congruent to  $1$ mod $r$. We cannot have $|{\rm Syl}_r(G)|=12$, or $G$ would have a normal $r$-complement, so the only possibility is $|{\rm Syl}_r(G)| = 6$ and $r=5$.

Answer (score 1):

The groups of order $p^2qr$ for distinct primes $p,q,r$ have been classified [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1986340?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) by Oliver G. Glenn in $1906$.

With the exception of the group of order $2^2\cdot 3\cdot 5$,  simply isomorphic with the icosahedron-group $A_5$, all groups of order $p^2qr$ are solvable.

Comment: Although this does somewhat answer the question, it doesn't help me much since I need to be able to prove it on my Abstract Algebra assignment. Thus, I hope that there exists a much more elementary proof, one that uses Sylow Theorems and similar "tools".

Comment: @mivan The proof there uses Sylow theorems and is not too complicated. You see from Derek's answer that Burnside's Transfer Theorem is used. Probably not something on your "Abstract Algebra assignment".

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for an "elementary" proof, I'll try to write one that doesn't use Burnside's transfer theorem.

Let $G$ be a simple group of order $p^2qr$, WLOG $q<r$. We call $n_p,n_q,n_r$ the numbers of the respective Sylow subgroups, which must be all greater than $1$: then, $n_p \in \{q,r,qr\}$ and $n_r \in \{p,p^2,pq,p^2q\}$. We also call $m \in \{1,p\}$ the largest cardinality of the intersection of two distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups.

First of all, we observe that $G$ has no subgroups of index $q$, otherwise it would be isomorphic to a subgroup of $A_q$, which has no elements of order $r$: in particular, $n_p \neq q$.

Case 1: $n_r \in \{p,p^2\}$.

This forces $p>r$: indeed, in both cases we must have $r|p^2-1$, i.e. $r|p\pm1$ and then $r \le p+1$, and the inequality $p>r$ only fails when $(p,r)=(2,3)$, which leaves no room for $q$. Then, since $n_p \ge p+1$, the only possibility for $n_p$ is $qr$.

Case 1.1: $n_r \in \{p,p^2\}$, $n_p=qr$ and $m=p$.

Let $P$ and $Q$ be two Sylow $p$-subgroups such that $|P \cap Q|=p$: then, $N_G(P \cap Q)$ has order a multiple of $p^2$ and it has more than one Sylow $p$-subgroup, so that it is forced to be the whole $G$, and $P \cap Q \triangleleft G$.

Case 1.2: $n_r \in \{p,p^2\}$, $n_p=qr$ and $m=1$.

There are exactly $qr(p^2-1)$ elements of order $p$ or $p^2$; among the remaining $qr$ elements, there are exactly $n_q(q-1)$ of order $q$ and $n_r(r-1)$ of order $r$, so that

$1+n_q(q-1)+n_r(r-1) \le qr \Rightarrow n_r(r-1) \le qr-1-n_q(q-1) < q(r-1) \Rightarrow n_r<q$,

which contradicts $n_r \ge r+1$.

Case 2: $n_r=p^2q$.

Arguing as in Case 1.2, there are exactly $p^2q$ elements of order $\neq r$, and if $m=1$ we would have $1+n_q(q-1)+n_p(p^2-1) \le p^2q \Rightarrow n_p<q$, contradiction. Therefore $m=p$, and taking $P,Q$ as in Case 1.1, $N_G(P \cap Q)$ has order $p^2q$ or $p^2r$: in the former case it is exactly the set of elements of order $\neq r$, so that it is a characteristic subgroup (and then normal), while in the latter it has index $q$ in $G$, but we had already ruled out this case at the beginning.

Case 3: $n_r=pq$ and $n_p=r$.

Write $r=kp+1$ and $pq=hr+1$, with $h,k \ge 1$. We have $pq=h(kp+1)+1=hkp+h+1$, so that $h=tp-1$ for some $t \ge 1$ and $q=hk+t$. Since $q<r$, we also have $(tp-1)k+t<kp+1 \Rightarrow (tp-p-1)k<1-t$, which is impossible if $t>1$, so that $t=1$ and $q=(p-1)k+1$. Finally, we have $k>1$ (otherwise $p=q$) and then $q>p$. Now, $n_p=r$ implies that any Sylow $p$-subgroup has a normalizer of order $p^2q$, so that the latter has a normal Sylow $q$-subgroup unless $(p,q)=(2,3)$ (which leads to $|G|=60$, in which case I take for granted that $G \cong A_5$), and then $n_q=r$. However, we should have $q|r-1=kp \Rightarrow q|k \Rightarrow q|\text{gcd}(k,q)=1$, impossible.

Case 4: $n_r=pq$ and $n_p=qr$.

If $m=1$, we get the same contradiction as in Case 1.2, therefore $m=p$, and similarly to Case 2, taking $P$ and $Q$ as usual, we must have $|N_G(P \cap Q)|=p^2q$. Since $N_G(P \cap Q)$ has more than one Sylow $p$-subgroup, it has a normal Sylow $q$-subgroup (by the classification of groups of order $p^2q$), so that the only possibility for $n_q$ is $r$, and then $r \equiv 1 (\bmod q)$. Also, since any Sylow $r$-subgroup $R$ has a normalizer of order $pr$, a subgroup $H<R$ of order $p$ cannot be normal in $R$, otherwise the index of $N_G(H)$ in $G$ would be $1$ or $q$, leading to a contradiction in both cases. Therefore $r \equiv 1 (\bmod p)$, and then $r \equiv 1 (\bmod pq)$, which contradicts $pq \equiv 1 (\bmod r)$.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is aimed not to use the Burnside's Transfer Theorem.

Let $G$ be a simple group of order $|G|=p^2 qr$ and let $P∈Syl_p (G)$, $Q∈Syl_q (G)$, $R∈Syl_r (G)$.

Assume (w.l.o.g) that $q<r$.  *Our goal will be to show that* $|G|=60$.

**(1)** $G$ *has no subgroup of order* $p^2 r$.
To see this, suppose the contrary: $|H|=p^2 r$. Then $|G∶H|=(p^2 qr)/(p^2 r)=q$. Let $G$ act by left multiplication on the set of all distinct left cosets of $H$ in $G$. This action affords a homomorphism $G→S_q$, so by the 1st Isomorphism Theorem, since $G$ is simple, $G≅L≤S_q$ and by the Lagrange’s Theorem  $|G| \ | \ |S_q |$ or $p^2 qr \ |\ q!$   ⇔   $p^2 r \ | \ (q-1)!$, but this is not possible since $q<r$ are primes. We’ve reached a *contradiction*.

---

**(2)** Choose $P_1,P_2∈Syl_p (G)$ over all pairs of distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups of G with the order $|P_1  ⋂ P_2 |$ being maximal.
Suppose $|P_1  ⋂ P_2 |>1$. Then $|P_1  ⋂ P_2 |=p$. Hence $|P_1 ∶P_1  ⋂ P_2 |=|P_2 ∶P_1  ⋂ P_2 |=p^2/p=p$, therefore $P_1  ⋂ P_2⊲P_1$,  $P_1  ⋂ P_2⊲P_2$ (as subgroups of index $p$ — the smallest prime dividing $p^2$) and so                                        $P_1,P_2≤N_G (P_1  ⋂ P_2 )$, therefore, since $|P_1 |=|P_2 |=p^2$, we have that  $p^2 \ | \ |N_G (P_1  ⋂ P_2 )|$ and $|N_G (P_1  ⋂ P_2 )|>p^2$ (otherwise there wouldn’t be enough elements in $N_G (P_1  ⋂ P_2 )$ to contain both $P_1,P_2$). Then by the Lagrange’s Theorem and **(1)** it is only possible that $|N_G (P_1  ⋂ P_2 )|=p^2 q$. Let’s denote $N_G (P_1  ⋂ P_2 )=M$. Consider the set $Syl_p (M)$. Because $|M|=p^2 q$, it follows that every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $M$ is also a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, that is, $Syl_p (M)⊆Syl_p (G)$. Hence $G$ acts transitively by conjugation on $Syl_p (M)$. The kernel $K$ of this action which is also a kernel of the afforded homomorphism $G→S_{|Syl_p (M)}|$  is $K=\bigcap_{i=1}^{|Syl_p (M)|} N_G (P_i)$.  Note that $P_1  ⋂ P_2$ lies in the intersection of all the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $M$. To see this, take a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $M$ containing $P_1  ⋂ P_2$, conjugate it to another Sylow $p$-subgroup of $M$ with some $x∈M$ and you get that $x(P_1  ⋂ P_2 ) x^{-1}=P_1  ⋂ P_2$ is contained in this another Sylow $p$-subgroup of $M$; since all the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $M$ are conjugate in $M$, it follows that $P_1  ⋂ P_2$ is contained in all Sylow $p$-subgroups $P_i$ of $M$. Therefore, $P_1  ⋂ P_2≤\bigcap_{i=1}^{|Syl_p (M)|} P_i$. Since $P_i≤N_G (P_i )$ for all $P_i∈Syl_p (M)$, it follows that $P_1  ⋂ P_2≤\bigcap_{i=1}^{|Syl_p (M)|} N_G (P_i)=K$, i.e., the kernel $K$ is nontrivial. Since  $K⊲G$ and $G$ is simple, this is a *contradiction*.

Thus, $|P_1  ⋂ P_2 |=1$. Then $P_i  ⋂ P_j=1$ for every pair $P_i,P_j ∈Syl_p (G)$. Hence the number of elements of $G$ contained in its Sylow $p$-subgroups is $(p^2-1) n_p$.
Consider $N_G (P)$. Obviously $P≤N_G (P)$, hence the Lagrange’s Theorem and **(1)** leave only two possibilities: $|N_G (P)|∈\{p^2,p^2 q\}$.

---

**(3)** Suppose $|N_G (P)|=p^2$. Then $n_p=|G∶N_G (P)|=(p^2 qr)/p^2 =qr$. Hence the number of elements of $G$ contained in its Sylow $p$-subgroups is $(p^2-1) n_p=(p^2-1)qr$. For $n_q$ and $n_r$ we have $n_q \ | \ p^2 r$ and $n_r \ | \ p^2 q$. Obviously $n_q≠1$ and $n_p≠1$ since $G$ is simple. Suppose $n_q=r$, $n_r=q$. Then the total number $A$ of elements of $G$ contained in its Sylow subgroups is  $A=(p^2-1)qr+(q-1)r+(r-1)q=p^2 qr-qr+qr-r+qr-q=p^2 qr+qr-(q+r)>p^2 qr=|G|$ Note that actually $n_r≠q$ since $q<r$ and so $n_r=q≢1 (mod \ r)$. Hence to satisfy the congruence condition there must be $n_r>q$ and because $n_r \ | \ p^2 q$ the minimal possible $n_r$ is either           $n_r=pq$  (if $p>q$) or $n_r=p^2$ (if $p<q$).  But  $A>|G|$ even for the lesser number of $n_r$, hence there must be $n_q<r$. Because $n_q \ | \ p^2 r$ the minimal possible $n_q$ is $n_q=p$ (assuming that $p<r$; if this assumption is not true, we reach a contradiction immediately).
If $n_r=pq$, then $$A=(p^2-1)qr+(q-1)p+(r-1)pq=p^2 qr-qr+pq-p+pqr-pq=p^2 qr+pqr-(qr+p)>p^2 qr=|G|$$
a *contradiction*.
If  $n_r=p^2$, then $p<q$ as was noted (and hence $p<q<r$). But now we cannot have $n_q=p$ because $n_q=p≢1(mod \ q)$. Hence, since $n_q \ | \ p^2 r$ and $n_q<r$, the minimal possible $n_q$ is $n_q=p^2$. But since $n_r=p^2$, by Sylow’s Theorem, $n_r=p^2≡1(mod \ r)$, hence $p^2>r$ and so $n_q≠p^2$ because there must be $n_q<r$. So there is no $n_q<r$ satisfying $n_q \ | \ p^2 r$.  We’ve reached a *contradiction*.

So, if $|N_G (P)|=p^2$, the total number $A$ of elements of $G$ contained in its Sylow subgroups exceeds $|G|$. So, $|N_G (P)|≠p^2$.

Thus, $|N_G (P)|=p^2 q$. Therefore, $n_p=|G∶N_G (P)|=(p^2 qr)/p^2 =r$. Also, because $P_i  ⋂ P_j=1$ for every pair $P_i,P_j ∈Syl_p (G)$, it follows that $n_p≡1(mod \ p^2 )$ and hence $r≡1(mod \ p^2 )$.

---

**(4)** Because $|N_G (P)|=p^2 q$ there is $Q∈Syl_q (G)$ such that $Q∈Syl_q (N_G (P))$. Denote $N_G (P)=N$.
Suppose $Q⊲N_G (P)$. Then $N_G (Q)=N_G (P)=N$. Hence  $n_p=n_q=|G∶N|=(p^2 qr)/(p^2 q)=r$. In **(3)** it was shown that $r≡1(mod \ p^2 )$ and hence $p^2  \ | \ r-1$.  Also since $n_q≡1(mod \ q)$ we have $r≡1(mod \ q)$ and hence  $q \ | \ r-1$. Therefore $p^2 q \ | \ r-1$ and so $r=1+kp^2 q$, where $k∈Z^+$. On the other hand, $n_r≡1(mod \ r)$, $n_r \ | \ p^2 q$. So the maximal possible $n_r$ is $n_r=p^2 q$. But even if $k=1$ and so $r=1+p^2 q$ we have that $n_r=p^2 q<(1+p^2 q)=r$, hence $n_r≢1(mod \ r)$, a *contradiction*. So, $Q⋪N_G (P)$.
Thus, $N_G (Q)≠N_G (P)$.

---

**(5)** Consider $N$ of order $|N|=p^2 q$. Since $P⊲N_G (P)=N$, it follows that $n_p (N)=1$. Since $Q$ is not normal in $N$, as it was just shown in **(4)**, it follows that $n_q (N)>1$. For the number of Sylow $q$-subgroups of $N$ we have: $n_q (N)≡1(mod \ q)$,  $n_q (N) \ | \ p^2$. Then it is either:  $n_q (N)=p$ (and so $p≡1(mod \ q)$) or $n_q (N)=p^2$.
Either way, though, $p^2≡1(mod \ q)$.

---

⦁ *Our subgoal from now on will be to establish the inequality relation between $p$ and $q$*.

**(6)** Consider $|N_G (Q)|$. In **(4)** it was shown that $N_G (Q)≠N_G (P)$, hence $|N_G (Q)|≠p^2 q$. Denote $N_G (Q)=H$.  Then, since $Q≤N_G (Q)=H$, by the Lagrange’s Theorem $q \ | \ |H|$ and therefore $|H|∈\{q,pq,qr,pqr\}$.

⦁ Suppose $|H|=q$. Then $n_q=|G∶N|=(p^2 qr)/q=p^2 r$. So we have $p^2 r≡1(mod \  q)$ and since $p^2≡1(mod \ q)$ (see **(5)**), it follows that $r≡1(mod \ q)$. On the other hand $r≡1(mod \ p^2)$ (see **(3)**). These conditions for $r$ taken together lead to the exactly the same *contradiction* as in **(4)**. So, $|H|≠q$.

⦁ Suppose $|H|=qr$. Then by Sylow’s Theorem, there is $R∈Syl_r (H)$ with $|R|=r$ and so $R∈Syl_r (G)$. Then, since $Q⊲H$ and $Q ⋂ R=1$, $H≅Q⋊R$. Since $Q⊲H$,  $H$ acts on $Q$ by conjugation. This action affords a homomorphism $H→Aut(Q)$ with the kernel $C_H (Q)$, hence by the 1st Isomorphism Theorem, $H⁄C_H (Q)≅L≤Aut(Q)$. Since $Q≅Z_q$, it follows that $Aut(Q)≅Z_{q-1}$. By the Lagrange’s Theorem, $|H⁄C_H (Q) | \ | \ |Aut(Q)|$ or $qr/|C_H (Q)| \ | \ (q-1)$. Since $Q$ is abelian, $Q≤C_H (Q)$. Because $r>q$,  $r∤(q-1)$, what forces $|C_H (Q)|=qr=|H|$ and so $Q≤Z(H)$. Then $H≅Q×R$, therefore $R⊲H$ and so $H≤N_G (R)$. Then it is either $|N_G (R)|=qr$ or $|N_G (R)|=pqr$ and hence $n_r=|G∶N_G (R)|=(p^2 qr)/qr=p^2$ or $n_r=|G∶N_G (R)|=(p^2 qr)/pqr=p$ correspondingly. Both cases though are not possible since there must be $n_r≡1(mod \ r)$ but $r≡1(mod \ p^2)$ (see **(3)**), hence $p^2<r$ and so $p^2≢1(mod \ r)$ and $p≢1(mod \ r)$. We’ve reached a *contradiction*. So, $|H|≠qr$.

⦁ Suppose $|H|=pqr$. As in the previous case, there is $R∈Syl_r (H)$ with $|R|=r$ and so $R∈Syl_r (G)$. Since $Q⊲H$, it follows that $QR<H$ and since $Q ⋂ R=1$, its order is $|QR|=qr$. Considering the action of $QR$ on $Q$ by conjugation exactly analogously to the previous case gives that $QR≅Q×R$, therefore $R⊲QR$, so $QR≤N_G (R)$, hence either $|N_G (R)|=qr$ or $|N_G (R)|=pqr$, what leads to exactly the same *contradiction* as in the previous case. So, $|H|≠pqr$.

Thus, $|N_G (Q)|=pq$.

---

**(7)** Suppose $p>q$.

- Then it may be $n_q (N)=p$ and so $p≡1(mod \ q)$ (see **(5)**). Suppose this holds true. Using the result of **(6)**, the number of Sylow $q$-subgroups of $G$ is $n_q=|G∶N_G (Q)|=(p^2 qr)/pq=pr$. So we have                                 $pr≡1(mod \ q)$ and since $p≡1(mod \ q)$ (by assumption), it follows that $r≡1(mod \ q)$. On the other hand $r≡1(mod \ p^2)$ (see **(3)**). These conditions for $r$ taken together lead to the exactly the same *contradiction* as in **(4)**. So,  $p≢1(mod \ q)$.
- Going back to **(5)**, we now have only one possibility left: $n_q (N)=p^2$. Therefore, $p^2≡1(mod \ q)   ⇔   q \ | \ p^2-1    ⇔    q \ | \ (p-1)(p+1)$. Since $p>q$,  $p$ must be an odd prime, i.e. $p>2$. Because $p$ is an odd prime, $(p-1)(p+1)$ is even, hence, since $q$ is also a prime, it can only be that $q=2$, so that $p≡1(mod \ 2)$. Thus, if $p>q$ the condition $n_q (N)=p^2$ implies  $p≡1(mod \ q)$, but $p≢1(mod \ q)$ as was shown just before. We’ve reached a *contradiction*.

Thus, $p<q$.

⦁ *So the inequality relation between $p,q,r$ is $p<q<r$*.

---

**(8)** Going back to **(5)**, we now have $|N|=p^2 q$ with $p<q$, therefore $p≢1(mod \ q)$. Because $n_q (N) \ | \ p^2$, $n_q (N)>1$ and $p≢1(mod \ q)$,  it can only be that $n_q (N)=p^2$. Then, as in **(7)**, we have $q \ | \ (p-1)(p+1)$, but now $p<q$. If $p$ is an odd prime, i.e. $p>2$, then $(p-1)(p+1)$ is even. Because $q>p$, $q$ is also an odd prime, hence $q \ ∤ \ (p-1)(p+1)$, a contradiction. So it can only be that $p=2$. Now $q \ | \ (2-1)(2+1)  ⇔  q \ | \ 3$, therefore it can only be that $q=3$.

Thus, $p=2,q=3$.

---

**(9)** Now $|G|=p^2 qr=2^2⋅3⋅r=12r$. Then for the number of Sylow $r$-subgroups of G we have: $n_r≡1(mod \ r)$, $n_r \ | \ 12$. Since $G$ is simple, $n_r≠1$, hence $n_r∈{2,3,4,6,12}$. Note that $n_r≠2$, because $r≠1$. Also $n_r≠3$, because this would imply $r=2=p$, but $r≠p$. Also $n_r≠4$, because this would imply $r=3=q$, but $r≠q$. So it there are only two possibilities: $n_r=6$ and so $r=5$, or $n_r=12$ and so $r=11$.
On the other hand, in **(4)** it was shown that $r≡1(mod \ p^2)$, therefore $r≡1(mod \ 4)$. Since $11≡3≢1(mod \ 4)$, it can only be that $r=5$, which does satisfy this condition.

Thus, $r=5$.

---

**(10)** Finally, we have $p=2, q=3, r=5$, therefore $|G|=p^2 qr=2^2⋅3⋅5=60$. Since $G$ is a simple group of order $60$, it is isomorphic to $A_5$.

Comment: This is lengthy, I know, but without using the Burnside's Transfer Theorem, the result seems not to be trivial to prove. And at the time I was assigned this task, I did not know (and actually wasn't supposed to know) the BTT.

Comment: I think it would make more sense to learn the proof of Burnside's Transfer Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

References to Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra, 3rd edition, 2004.

If $p^{2}qr$ is odd, $G$ is solvable ((Feit-Thompson) Theorem~6.1.11(3)) so there is a proper normal subgroup, a contradiction. It must be that $p^{2}qr$ is even and $q=2$ or $r=2$ implies a normal subgroup of index $2$ (Exercise~4.2.13), again a contradiction. Then $p=2$ so $\left|G\right|=4qr$ and $q<r$ implies $n_{r}$ is either $2q$ or $4q$. If $n_{r}=4q$ there is the minimal (the minimal index is $r$) element count $4q\left(r-1\right)+r\left(q-1\right)+\left(r\cdot2+1\right)+1>4qr$, a contradiction. It must be that $n_{r}=2q$ and $2r>2q$ so $n_{r}=r+1=2q$. Since $n_{q}$ must be at least $2q+1>r$, $n_{q}$ is either $2r$ or $4r$. Observe that $4r=8q-4\equiv 1\bmod 5$ and $r=2\cdot 5-1=9$ is not prime, a contradiction. It must be that $n_{q}=2r=4q-2\equiv 1\bmod 3$ so $q=3$ and $r=5$. Thus the result.

Comment: I am curious, is this a verbatim quotation from the book? I don't have my copy of Dummit and Foote nearby.

Comment: Not that I have read.